# how to precisely identify type in TS error messages when the same type name is used

Tags: typescript

I sometimes get TS error messages like the following:

> TS2345: Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of
> type 'Element | Component<any, {}, any> | null | undefined'.   Type
> 'Element' is missing the following properties from type
> 'Component<any, {}, any>': context, setState, forceUpdate, render, and
> 2 more.

I don't see how an argument of type `A` cannot be assignable to a parameter of type `A | B | C`. What am I missing?

Comment: The error message is not about different `Element` types as far as I can see, but rather the conflict between `Element` and `Component<...>`. What's the code that's causing this error?

Comment: @Etheryte I've updated the question to clarify what I am asking. I am trying to understand the error condition in general, not fix the particular problem that's why I'm not supplying the code.